# Send XHR request from html file wrapped into webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, webview

I have index.html file it contains CSS,HTML and JavaScript code JavaScript code is sending request using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to .php file on the server, .php file echoing some data.

I wrap HTML code into android app WebView as string (not using loadUrl function) using code that i found on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java) source

**Java:**

```
// Create an unencoded HTML string
// then convert the unencoded HTML string into bytes, encode
// it with Base64, and load the data.
String unencodedHtml =
     "<html><body>'%23' is the percent code for ‘#‘ </body></html>";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(),
        Base64.NO_PADDING);
myWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Also enabled Internet and JavaScript support

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But i can't send GET/POST request from JavaScript inside app to remote .php file on server.

Everything is working if i upload index.html file to server and send request to .php file I can send request without CORS issue from localhost too.

Is there any way to avoid wrapp entire Website into WebView and use loadUrl instead of loadData function or am i missing something?

Can i send XHR/Fetch requests from app to server and receive data into WebView?

I am still searching for answer but still not found working solution

Comment: Not sure, but there's a chance it can be a CORS issue. You should look into the logs for more information

Comment: No CORS Issue when using localhost